# Check that has void

Tags: united-states, banking, check

Working for walmart I was payed on the 4th and on the 6th the company took the money out of my account and wrote me a paper check.

A few days later I try to mobile upload to netspend, the first step said to take picture of front, second is the back, then submit. 3, sign the back then 4 write void on back and send in and should be approved in minutes.

My check was declined and now I can't cash it anywhere. My job will not reissue a check and neither will money network or netspend. What can I do?

Comment: So were you paid by direct deposit, and then that transaction was later reversed? Then you were given a paper check for the same amount?

Comment: Is Walmart your employer, or are you a contractor working for a different company?

Comment: When you say your check was declined, do you mean to say that Netspend told you that the check was not good?  What was the explanation that they gave you?  When you went to your employer with the voided check and asked for a new one, what was the explanation they gave you on why they wouldn't give you a new check?

Comment: I think your steps are out of order. It should be 1. sign the back, 2. take pictures of front and back, 3. submit, ?4. write void so that it can't be cashed elsewhere? If you sent in a photo with void written on the back, why should they accept it?

Comment: Also, you need to sign before taking pic of the back.

Comment: What state are you in? I believe at some if not all states have laws that your employer must re-issue your check if it is damaged or destroyed (they may be able to deduct a reasonable amount to cover the cost of stopping payment on the lost check and preparing the replacement check).

Comment: To summarize: 1) You did work. 2) you did not get paid. Talk to HR, throw those 2 facts at them, demand payment. If they're reluctant to do that, sue in small claims court.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than "Void", my banks ask for you to endorse as "Electronically Submitted".

Your company should re-issue the check. I suggest you contact your state's Department of Labor if there is a problem. Your immediate supervisor probably doesn't handle this, but look for the Accounting Department.